# Difference between single mode and multi mode optical fibres?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

What is the difference between [single mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-mode_optical_fiber) and [multi mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_optical_fiber) optical fibres? First off, I guess that by *modes* we mean the spatial modes of the electric (or magnetic?) field right?

Now: what makes a fibre able to support more than a single mode? I mean, what aspect of its structure corresponds to which mode(s) can be transmitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the diameter of the fiber core. In a single-mode fiber, only the lowest-order mode fits physically into the fiber.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume either electric or magnetic field for simplicity, they both are present in light as it's electromagnetic wave.

Now, mode is a sustainable pattern in the fiber optic cable. Imagine waves on a string, only the integral multiples of half wavelengths effectively form a mode. 
Let there be a complex output pattern at the output of a string. It turns out if we aren't playing with it continuously, it will be essentially periodic, maybe long period.
And we can always reduce it via fourier transforms to a sum of some basic modes. 
Imagine the output at the end of a MMF(multi mode fiber) as waves on a string with intensity output as the wave amplitude on the string. It may be complex. But you can simplify the output by considering it as a sum of several modes.
You can play with waves on a string here. It won't do a fourier transform though.
http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/wave-on-a-string/wave-on-a-string_en.html

The concept is a little different for SMF and MMF.
In case of SMF, Ray theory fails and light propagates as a wavefront as explained here:
[Single-mode fibers and ray-theory of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119803/single-mode-fibers-and-ray-theory-of-light)

Answer (score 0):

The V-number defines the mode of any fiber. It depends on wavelength, diameter of fiber and refractive index.

[image]

The v number is

\begin{align}
\ V^2 &= \frac{2}{} (_1^2−_2^2)\\\\
 \end{align}

Each mode has an effective index that can be defined by:
\begin{align}
\ _ = _ \frac{2}{}\\\\
 \end{align}

The effective index tells you how tightly the mode is confined to the waveguide core

- Guided mode _ < _ < _
- Tightly confined to the core _ ~ _
- Weakly confined to the core _  ~ _
- Unguided or radiating modes _<_