# How does light travel through an optical fibre of diameter less than the distance between the wave's crest and the trough?

Tags: wave-particle-duality, quantum-tunneling

It is known that optical fibres use light waves for faster communications and also in many other things like measuring and all.....everything is fine till the wave just fits into the fibre ....but what about when the optical fibres are made in such a way that their diameter is less than the distance between the wave's crest and the trough? these fibres act like a rail and the wave is like a train on it .....but the wave actally comes out of it and enters the fibre again right? If we reffer this phenomenon as tunneling(where the photon is continiously entering and exiting the fibre) then isnt there is also a probability(a considerable one) that the wave can leave the fibre? Even if it doesn't ...... shouldnt continious tunneling affect the probability amplitude(but it doesnt)?

Comment: Do not have an answer for you, but had to comment on the fiber optic. I had no idea that someone could make a fiber optic strand in the 750 nm range. A human hair is about 100,000nm. Impressive!

Comment: Yes I do know that it is next to impossible to create a fibre that thin. The reason for my question lies in this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmEAes44j5s
It is a 21min 49sec video so if you get bored just skip the first 19mins then you will understand why i asked such an invalid question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the absolute basic mechanism for transmission of light using optical fibres. The phenomenon of total internal reflection is at play here. The diameter being less than the wavelength, has no obvious effect on the transmission, apart from being almost impossible to construct.Also,they would be rather ineffective for carrying sufficient information. The cladding makes the fibers act as waveguides. The wave can leave the fiber. We know that there are losses in optical fiber transmission, minimizing which is the latest job of engineers in this field. Using wave functions to analyse tunneling effects is rather unnecessary, because in reality, losses occur due to a multitude of reasons, and tunneling losses make up less than 1-2% of these reasons.

**MAIN REASONS FOR LOSSES**(OPTICAL ATTENUATION):

1) Bending of fibers

2)Improper joining of 2 optical fiber cores, leading to losses at the junction.

3)Irregularities on the inner surface, can cause the reflected wave to be incident on the other surface at a 'bad' angle, which cannot undergo total internal reflection anymore, and escapes the core, causing information loss.

For a more mathematical approach in calculating losses in optical fibers, i suggest you read [THIS PDF.](http://opti500.cian-erc.org/opti500/pdf/sm/Module3%20Optical%20Attenuation.pdf)

Comment: i know that my question does not make that much sense but if you visit this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmEAes44j5s
I think you will understand why i asked such a question.
The reason for my question lies after the first 19 mins so if you get bored skip the first 19 mins

Comment: can you summarise the video? what is amiss?

Comment: just watch the last 3 mins

Comment: As far as I could understand, the only reason to narrow down the tube, is to ensure that every point on the wall receives a photon soon enough. When a little amount of water flows in the huge underground sewage tunnels, most of the tunnel walls are not in contact with the water(they cannot sense its presence). If we narrow down the wall, down to the size of a straw, then the same amount of water flowing through it will now wet the entire surface. The same concept is required here, as the video showed how proteins attached to the wall of the fiber must receive the light, to trigger the sensor

Comment: Dripto........watch the video again....you are not getting my point

Comment: No one is. I suggest you wait for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Optical fibers (the inner core) are normally wider than a couple wavelengths (8-9 $\mu m$ diameter for 1.5 $\mu m$ wavelength). In general, wave guides have a cut-off wave length (for each mode) beyond which no propagating waves (only damped waves) along the wave guide exist. For the lowest mode, this occurs when half the wavelength of the internal "plane wave" becomes comparable to the diameter of the guide. This is not completely true in dielectric waveguides like optical fibers. They use an outer (cladding) refractive index which is lower than the refractive index of the core so that due to total reflection at the operating wave lengths, only evanescent (no propagating) waves penetrate the outer dielectric which works like a perfect reflector. Increasing the wave length in an optical fiber is equivalent to decreasing the incident angle of the internal "plane wave" on the outer cladding so that eventually no total reflection occurs anymore and no true cut-off wave length exists. In this wave length region, propagating waves still exist along the optical fiber but their loss is very high due to the wave energy leaving the fiber. Therefore, waves with half wavelengths comparable to the diameter of the fiber core are not useful.
Note: "Tunneling", i.e., loss of photons due to transmission through the cladding layer (in spite of being in the total reflection regime) plays only a minor role in the loss of propagating modes of the optical fiber.

Note: I found another post relevant for this topic:[Why does a single mode fibre have a cutoff wavelength?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126124/why-does-a-single-mode-fibre-have-a-cutoff-wavelength/126649#126649)